# What is a rubber technic beam with two axle holes?

Tags: part-identification, inventory

I'm starting an inventory on Rebrickable, and came across a part that I can't find listed.  I can describe it clearly enough and I know how it might be used (but not why it's better than the "normal" plastic), but I want to be able to add it to the tracked inventory in the database.  So how do I "find" it on Rebrickable?

This looks just like a beam that has two axle holes and is made of rubber rather than ABS.  It is a unit (not half-unit) thick.

Comment: Couple more resources alternatives to Rebrickable you can use to check inventory and identify parts: Bricklink.con and Brickset.com . Each has its own benefits and disadvantages, but otherwise very useful. Sometimes it is easier to check inventory for couple of recent sets to see which parts they have. Especially if the part is rather fresh.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That sounds like [Technic, Axle Connector Double - Flexible Rubber](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=45590#T=C&C=11), known on rebrickable as [Technic Axle Connector Double Flexible [Rubber]](https://rebrickable.com/parts/45590/technic-axle-connector-double-flexible-rubber/).

[image]

It's used for various purposes - eg. when some extra "give" is needed, or some extra friction, or to dampen a movement, or ...

Answer (score 9):

On Bricklink, it's called "Technic, Axle Connector Double - Flexible Rubber" - part number 45590

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=45590

[image: lego part 45590]